# Substitution for Landau's O notation formula

Tags: complexity-theory, landau-notation

I found the following description when I was reading a paper on computational complexity theory.

> This can be done ... in time 2<sup>*n*</sup>･poly(log*s*,*n*)+2<sup>*O*(log*s*)<sup>*c*</sup></sup>. For *s*≤2<sup>*n*<sup>*o*(1)</sup></sup>, the runtime is 2<sup>*n*</sup>･poly(*n*).

I know this means substituting *s*≤2<sup>*n*<sup>*o*(1)</sup></sup> for 2<sup>*n*</sup>･poly(log*s*,*n*)+2<sup>*O*(log*s*)<sup>*c*</sup></sup> results in 2<sup>*n*</sup>･poly(*n*), but I don't know how this is done. So please tell me the calculation process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let us notice that $\log s = n^{o(1)} = o(n)$, and so $\mathit{poly}(\log s, n) = \mathit{poly}(n)$. This shows that the first summand is $2^n \mathit{poly}(n)$.

Next, since $\log s = n^{o(1)}$, also $O(\log s) = n^{o(1)}$ (since constants are $n^{o(1)}$) and $O(\log s)^c = n^{o(1)}$ (since a constant multiple of $o(1)$ is also $o(1)$), hence the second summand is $2^{n^{o(1)}} = o(2^n)$. So the first summand is more significant.

Comment: I'd appreciate your answer.
I was able to take the first step in your answer, but I didn't know the second step. Now I clearly understand it thanks to your explicit explanation.